# Interface for ENUM for all enums implements equals method

Tags: java, enums

I have 3 enums. I need that all enums implements my methods

```
public interface BaseEnum {
    public String getFontName();
    public File getLocation();
}
```

I need this when I implements BaseEnum:

```
public enum TestEnum implements BaseEnum{
    NEW(0),
    NEW2(1);
    private int value;

    TestEnum (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

 //I need 
  @Override
  public String getFontName() {
    return fontName;
  }

  @Override
  public File getLocation() {
    return location;
  }
}
```

But I have this:

```
public enum ServerStatus implements BaseEnum{
    NEW(0) {
        @Override
        public String getFontName() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public File getLocation() {
            return null;
        }
    },
    NEW2(1) {
        @Override
        public String getFontName() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public File getLocation() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    private int value;

    ServerStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I fuond in [this article](http://blog.pengyifan.com/how-to-extend-enum-in-java/)

I want create converter

```
public class StatusConverter<T> implements AttributeConverter<T,Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(T t) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToEntityAttribute(Integer integer) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but I need know that T  has needed methosd and I want

```
implements AttributeConverter<T extends BaseEnum,Integer>
```

EDIT:

```
public interface BaseEnum<T> {
    Integer getValue();
    T parce(int id);
}
```

my enum

```
public enum ServerStatus implements BaseEnum<ServerStatus> {
    NEW(0),
    NEW2(1);
    private int value;

    ServerStatus(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public ServerStatus parce(int id) {
        ServerStatus status = null; // Default
        for (ServerStatus item : ServerStatus.values()) {
            if (item.getValue() == id) {
                status = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

and converter:

```
public class StatusConverter<T extends BaseEnum<T>> implements AttributeConverter<T,Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(T t) {
        return t.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToEntityAttribute(Integer integer) {
        return T.;//how can I get parse()???
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would your `fontName` & `location` come from ?

Comment: Did you try `public class StatusConverter<T extends BaseEnum> implements AttributeConverter<T,Integer> { ...}`?

Comment: @ Ted Hopp I edit question